# Google Sheets Script - How to select a random selection of cells according to a predefined set of rules

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, random

Hey guys I'm a beginner in Google Apps Script and I'm having trouble writing a script.

Here's my problem : I have a sheet B with with a list of 77 companies, their employee count and their size ("very small, small, medium, big") and I would like to select a random selection of companies according to a predefined set of rules, and display them in sheet A. ([here's my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HaVypJYMpzKXTNrXEY73ieuWGmozAjHrMMr4zW9k0Rg/edit?usp=sharing))

For example, I'd like to select 2 very small companies, 3 small companies, 4 medium companies, and 1 big company every time I click on a button.

When I click on the button, I'd like the list to reset and select new companies.

Here's my code so far , but I have trouble figuring out to complete it :

```
var companyList = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Company List");
var lastrow = getLastPopulatedRow(companyList);
var dataCompanyList = companyList.getDataRange().getValues();

var verysmall = 0;
var small = 0;
var medium = 0;
var big = 0;

var verysmallAlternate = 0;
var smallAlternate = 0;
var mediumAlternate = 0;
var bigAlternate = 0;

var breakLoop = 90000;
var companyList = []; 

function gethashtags() {
  
  while (verysmall<2)
  {
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (77));
    if (dataCompanyList[randomNum][2] == "verysmall")

{ 
company = dataCompanyList[randomNum][0];
verysmall++;
companyList.push(dataCompanyList[randomNum][0]);
}

{
verysmallAlternate++;
if(verysmallAlternate>breakLoop) {
verysmall;
}

while (small<3)
  {
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (77));
    if (dataCompanyList[randomNum][2] == "verysmall")

{ 
company = dataCompanyList[randomNum][0];
small++;
companyList.push(dataCompanyList[randomNum][0]);
}

{
smallAlternate++;
if(smallAlternate>breakLoop) {
small++;
}

while (medium<4)
  {
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (77));
    if (dataCompanyList[randomNum][2] == "medium")

{ 
company = dataCompanyList[randomNum][0];
medium++;
companyList.push(dataCompanyList[randomNum][0]);
}

{
mediumAlternate++;
if(mediumAlternate>breakLoop) {
medium++;
}

while (big<1)
  {
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (77));
    if (dataCompanyList[randomNum][2] == "big")

{ 
company = dataCompanyList[randomNum][0];
big++;
companyList.push(dataCompanyList[randomNum][0]);
}

{
bigAlternate++;
if(bigAlternate>breakLoop) {
big++;
}
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to make this work and display the companyList Array in the cell in the sheet A.

Comment: Can you specify the issue? Is it when getting the companies or when trying to show them on the sheet?

Comment: @Kessy I had issues with both !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The following script calculates a random list of predefined company hashtags and
  company sizes. You can adjust the number of companies you would like
  to return per category in the `selection` parameter.
- This list is then copy pasted into a selected range, in this case starting cell
  B6. You can adjust the starting cell by modifying the `row_to_copy` and `column_to_copy` parameters.
- To assign the `getRandomCompanies` function to the icon button in your sheet, simply right click on the icon, choose *assign a script* and specify the name of the function: `getRandomCompanies`.
- After these steps, every time you click on the button, a different list of companies will be generated.

---

### Solution:

```
function getRandomCompanies() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh_comp = ss.getSheetByName('Company List');
  const sh_gen = ss.getSheetByName('Company generator');
  const companies = sh_comp.getRange('A2:C'+sh_comp.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  const selection = {
  "very small":2,
  "small":3,
  "medium":4,
  "big":1
  }
  
  const finalComps = [];  
  Object.keys(selection).forEach(c=>{
  
     var tempAr = companies.filter(row=>row[2]===c).map(x => x[0]);
     var tempCr = companies.filter(row=>row[2]===c).map(x => x[2]);
     var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempAr.length) ;
     Array.from({ length: selection[c] }, x => {
     finalComps.push([tempAr[rn],tempCr[rn]]);
     tempAr.splice(rn, 1);
     tempCr.splice(rn, 1);
   
  });
  })
  
  // B6
  const row_to_copy = 6; // select the starting row to copy
  const column_to_copy = 2; // select the starting column to copy
  const range_to_copy = sh_gen.getRange(row_to_copy,column_to_copy,finalComps.length,finalComps[0].length);
  
  range_to_copy.clearContent(); //clear old values
  range_to_copy.setValues(finalComps);
  
}
```

---

### Output:

[image: result]

---

### References:

**Google Apps Script:**

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

**JavaScript:**

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: this is fantastic, and thank you so much for including references to the formulas you used, it's very useful as a beginner :)

Comment: thanks ! sorry to bother you again, but I have been studying the script and I don't think I understand exactly what this line does : "const companies = sh_comp.getRange('A2:C'+sh_comp.getLastRow()).getValues();". I see that you're getting the whole data range, but why do you need to add "sh_comp.getLastRow()"? Can't you just use get.LastRow alone to get the last row of the A2:C range ?

Comment: @monicab no worries. It gets the values of A2:C until the **last row with content**. In your case, the last row with content is row 78. Therefore this expression `'A2:C'+sh_comp.getLastRow()` is equivalent to `A2:C78`. The advantage of this approach is that it is dynamic. If you add a new row of values, then it will give you automatically `A2:C79` and so on.

Comment: Oh ok. I was asking because I have noticed that sometimes , there's blank fields when I run the script, so I thought that this line of code was getting the whole range... The issue comes from somewhere else in the script then

Comment: @monicab what do you mean blanks? could you elaborate or send a screenshot of your issue. If the issue is irrelevant, could you please post another question regarding that? Thanks a lot :)